# Why does the start() method of MediaRecorder throw an IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, illegalstateexception, user-permissions

I am trying to record audio but the `start()` method of `MediaRecorder` class throws an `IllegalStateException`.
I use the following code:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/");
try {
    recorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("Try","Exception");
recorder.start();
```

And following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 13):

`recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/");` is setting a directory, not a file.

Replace that with:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFileName += "/youraudiofile.3gp";
```

Using "/sdcard" hard codes a path which is fragile, so use the above.

Also, for this to work you must add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission solved my problem . Thank you DJC.

Answer (score 7):

`IllegalstateException` is thrown when the `MediaRecorder.prepare` method is not called, or called after `MediaRecorder.start`, or called before configuring audio/video sources, format and encoders.

The correct order of configuration mentioned in camera developer guide in the Android documentation:

1. camera unlock
2. control of camera to media recorder -> setCamera
3. set audio/video source, format,encoder
4. prepare
5. start

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Changing the order of format and encoder made it work. The order is source, format, encoder. Thanks!!